# how can I show progressbar in WPF for DB actions?

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I want to show my application user a progressbar for following actions:

1. when they provide login information in WPF and hit submit/OK whatever.
2. when they request any information from DB (select command execution).

Thank You

Comment: 1) For any progress bar you implement, you need value source for that. databASEs usually do not provide such information, so progressbar's states can only be 0% and 100%.
2) if your question is about using progressbar control itself, should you refer to books for beginners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A login to the database is an atomic operation.  So you can't really show a progress bar.  You ***can*** show a **waiting indicator** *(hour glass)*, or an **indeterminate progress bar** *(which is really just a waiting indicator that looks like a progress bar).*

For a query that gets data, you can show progress by paging the result set.  There are multiple ways to do this depending on the database/ORM you use.  The general principle is to set up a worker thread and grab data one page at a time.  After you grab a page, switch context to the UI thread and update the screen to show how much data you grabbed.